# Enviar SMS pelo PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, sms

Tenho um gateway de SMS que recebe os dados do meu form neste padrao:

```
<?php
include "smsGateway.php";
$smsGateway = new SmsGateway('demo@smsgateway.me', 'password');

$deviceID = 1;
$numbers = ['+44771232343', '+44771232344'];
$message = 'Hello World!';

$options = [
'send_at' => strtotime('+10 minutes'), // Send the message in 10 minutes
'expires_at' => strtotime('+1 hour') // Cancel the message in 1 hour if the     message is not yet sent
];

//Please note options is no required and can be left out
$result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToManyNumbers($number, $message, $deviceID, $options);
?>
```

Envio os numeros, por meio de um SELECT *  do meu banco de dados, dou print em um campo input e envio o form. Porem, a operadora não deixa enviar mais de 15 mensagens simultaneo. Teria como enviar um a um, mas dando apenas um SEND no formulário?

Comment: Um laço de repetição não resolveria o problema?

Comment: A primeira coisa que me veio na cabeça foi o que o @MarcelodeAndrade disse, um laço de repetição, for, foreach, while, o array $numbers vc já tem.

Comment: Experimenta usar o método `sleep()`. Ele faz com que o script PHP atrase pelo tempo definido para depois ser executado... Outra coisa que você pode fazer é usar um `<meta refresh>`

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de fazer isso, é criando um loop, e uma checagem pelo status de envio:

1) No select do seu banco, crie um campo: `status_envio` com o valor **0** como default.

2) Depois faça um select com a condição: `WHERE statust_envio=0 LIMIT 15`.

3) A cada ocorrência de **15** envios, atualize o status destes registros para **1**.

4) Quando não encontrar mais registros, informe o final do processo.

5) Coloque ao final do loop da execução do script, a impressão de uma `metatag` ou de um javascript com um timeOut.

```
$timeRefresh = '15'; //15 segundos

$url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

$result = array();
if (count($numbers)) {
   foreach ($numbers as $key => $number) {
       $result[$key] = $smsGateway->sendMessageToManyNumbers($number, $message, $deviceID, $options);
       if ($result[$key]) {
          $update = $smsGateway->updateStatus($number, 1);
       }
   }
  echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"{$timeRefresh};URL={$url}\">";
} else {
//e reatualize todo o banco novamente com status = 0 se precisar que esse processo seja repetido toda vez que chegar ao final e precisar enviar a página
  $update = $smsGateway->updateStatus(null, 0);
  echo "Fim dos envios!";

}
```

**OBS:** Método de checagem deve fazer um update no status:

```
public function updateStatus($number = null, $status = 0)
{
   $executed = null;

   if ( $number != null ) {
       $SQL = 'UPDATE tabela_sms set statust_envio=:status where number=:number';
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare($SQL);
       $executed = $stmt->execute(['status' => $status, 'number'=>$number]);
   } else {
      //se for nulo, atualiza o status para todos
       $SQL = 'UPDATE tabela_sms set statust_envio=:status where 1';
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare($SQL);
       $executed = $stmt->execute(['status' => $status]);
   }
   return $executed; 
}
```

Comment: Este código que colei, se refere a como o gateway, nao tenho acesso, visto ele ser terceirizado, aceita os dados. Eu fiz no form o envio, o post vai para este gateway.

Comment: Tudo bem, Leandro, eu fiz um exemplo, vc não precisa criar o método dentro do gateway, faça ele no seu sistema. Você só precisa ter acesso ao campo do status.

Comment: entendi, vou testar aqui. Obrigado ^^

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando um laço de repetição você solucionaria esse problema da seguinte forma:

```
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $result[] = $smsGateway->sendMessageToManyNumbers($number, $message, $deviceID, $options);
}
```

Se houver um limite de tempo para envio dos SMSs, podes adicionar um [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sleep.php).